# When I run protractor tests why do i get SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number?

Tags: protractor

```
SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

My spec is:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://google.com/');  // <-- not https! (though I did try it!)
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Google');
  }); 
});
```

Whatever URL address I try I get this error

```
$ protractor conf.js                                                                                                                                                                               
[12:59:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver                                                                                                                                           
[12:59:46] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at https://localhost:4444/wd/hub                                                                                                                   
[12:59:46] E/launcher - EPROTO write EPROTO 140666782832512:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:                 

[12:59:46] E/launcher - Error: EPROTO write EPROTO 140666782832512:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:          

    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/durrantm/Dropbox/90_2019/work/code/js/protractor/protractortest.org/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:238:15)                                  
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)                                                                                                                                                        
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)                                                                                                                                       
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
```

In another window I have server running

12:43:28.246 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444

and in a browser you can see [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `config.js`

I had

```
seleniumAddress: 'https://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

but I needed:

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
```